# Python way to run git log command to fetch details of repository without cloning it

Tags: python, git, bitbucket, branch, git-branch

Is there a Python way to run git log command to fetch details of repository without cloning it?
I want to run commands on bitbucket server to find all activities of a repository.

Comment: Is there even a git way of doing that? If you can find the correct git command, you can use the `sh` package to easily run the command from Python.

Comment: I want to run this command to get all the details git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `sh` package: `pip install sh`. Then do:

```
from sh import git

commit_messages = git.log(
    pretty='format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"', 
    n=50, 
    _tty_out=False
)
```

Or, using only built-in modules:

```
from subprocess import Popen

with Popen(['git', 'log', '--pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"']) as proc:
    commit_messages = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: I am using windows so pbs will work here. I have downloaded pbs source and did like this python setup.py install so that all the packages are compiled. when i do from pbs import git it throws unresolved reference. Any idea what can be missing. Can't do pip install due to restrictions.

Comment: Edited my answer to include possible solution for Windows. I don't have a Python for Windows handy.

Comment: Thank-You i believe it should work.Currently i'm observing WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.Let me check

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the exact location of the git executable?

Comment: I tried like this : os.system('git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s') It worked.

Comment: Are you sure that worked? `os.system` will print to stdout, so you'll have to jump through hoops to access the output in Python. That's what `Popen` does automatically for you.

Comment: I can see the output but i cannot capture it due to limitations of os.system. I am trying with subprocess now.